# Mysql showing type error in python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I wrote the following code to write into mysql database. It shows "%d format: a number is required, not str"

whereas when I print number, it shows 6. why so ??

```
for i in range(len(text1)):
            try1="INSERT INTO `crawl_url_attribute_css_sel_value`(`crawl_item_id`,`crawl_url_attribute_css_sel_id`,`value`,`reconciled`)\
                 VALUES(%s,%d,%s,FALSE) "

            values=(prodlist[i].get_attribute(result1[4]), int(number), db.escape_string(text1[i].text))
            print number
            cursor.execute(try1,values)
            db.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use %s placeholder.

```
for i in range(len(text1)):
        try1="INSERT INTO `crawl_url_attribute_css_sel_value` 
        (`crawl_item_id`,  `crawl_url_attribute_css_sel_id`, `value`, `reconciled`)\
        VALUES(%s,%s,%s,FALSE)"

        values=(prodlist[i].get_attribute(result1[4]), int(number), db.escape_string(text1[i].text))
        print number
        cursor.execute(try1,values)
        db.commit()
```

You can read the explanation [here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples)

> To perform a query, you first need a cursor, and then you can execute
>   queries on it:
>
> c=db.cursor() max_price=5 c.execute("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM
>   breakfast
>             WHERE price < %s""", (max_price,))
>
> In this example, max_price=5 Why, then, use %s in the string? Because
>   MySQLdb will convert it to a SQL literal value, which is the string
>   '5'. When it's finished, the query will actually say, "...WHERE price
>   < 5".